# Comparing json files of array of nested hash in perl

Tags: json, perl

I have 2 JSON files file1.json and file2.json. I want to compare the contents in it in Perl Language

---

*file1.json*

```
   [{
     "id": 12036289,
     "name": "DEFAULT ADMIN",
     "email": "admin@saurabh.com",
     "groups": [{
        "id": 12036287,
        "name": "Service Admin"
     }],
     "department": {
         "id": 12036288,
         "name": "Service Admin"
     },
     "adminUser": true
  }, {
     "id": 12046238,
     "name": "saurabh",
     "email": 
     "vbdfuyqwvbvvbduiqwvbduyvbqwuidvbq@saurabh.com",
     "groups": [{
         "id": 12046237,
         "name": "uiwgbfuisaufusgafuuuuuuuuuuuuugsdaaaaaaiqd"
     }],
     "department": {
        "id": 12046236,
        "name": "uiwvbdusguuuuuuuuuuuuuuugsdaaaaaaiuad2"
     },
     "adminUser": false
  }]
```

*file2.json*

```
 [{
    "id": 12046238,
    "name": "saurabh",
    "email": 
    "vbdfuyqwvbvvbduiqwvbduyvbqwuidvbq@saurabh.com",
    "groups": [{
       "id": 12046237,
       "name": "uiwgbfuisaufusgafuuuuuuuuuuuuugsdaaaaaaiqd"
    }],
    "department": {
       "id": 12046236,
       "name": "uiwvbdusguuuuuuuuuuuuuuugsdaaaaaaiuad2"
    },
    "adminUser": false
 }, {
   "id": 12036289,
   "name": "DEFAULT ADMIN",
   "email": "admin@saurabh.com",
   "groups": [{
       "id": 12036287,
       "name": "Service Admin"
    }],
    "adminUser": true,
    "department": {
       "id": 12036288,
       "name": "Service Admin"
     }
 }]
```

Here the contents are not in order but same. What i tried was to decode the json file and compare the arrays using `cmp_deeply()` function. But i was not able to do that. Do anyone have some approach to this problem?

---

**EDIT**   code supplied in a comment

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use JSON;
use Test::Deep;

my $file1;
#slurp mode 
{ 
    open(FILE,'<','file1.json');
    local $/ = undef;
    $file1 = <FILE>;
}

my $file2;
#slurp mode
{ 
    open(FILE,'<','file2.json');
    local $/ = undef;
    $file2 = <FILE>;
}

my @array1 = @{decode_json $file1};
my @array2 = @{decode_json $file2};
print @array1;

print cmp_deeply( @array1, @array2 );
```

Comment: `cmp_deeply` needs references to lists if you expect that to work...

Comment: @zdim i tried formating but its not working.. so can you help me without that?

Comment: I added and formatted the code. It appears that you only need to pass array references to the [Test::Deeply::cmp_deeply](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Deep#cmp_deeply) (and a name for the test).  Then you don't have to dereference what the decoder returns either, just use arrayrefs.

Comment: (it's `Test::Deep`, not "Deeply" as in the typo above. the link is valid)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my @array1 = @{decode_json $file1};
my @array2 = @{decode_json $file2};
print cmp_deeply( @array1, @array2 );
```

should be

```
my @array1 = @{decode_json $file1};
my @array2 = @{decode_json $file2};
print cmp_deeply( \@array1, \@array2 );
```

It would be even better to avoid the useless copying.

```
my $array1 = decode_json $file1;
my $array2 = decode_json $file2;
print cmp_deeply( $array1, $array2 );
```